# Microsoft Dynamics Nav 2009 user

Tags: c#, powershell, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2009

In Microsoft Dynamics Nav 2013 and higher, Microsoft announced powershell cmdlets and its very easy to get all Nav users using powershell command `Get-NAVServerUser`

Any idea how to get all users in Nav 2009 and lower where this is not supported? I need a way to get this users programmatically using powershell or c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent to the powershell commands before NAV2013.

In NAV 2009 you can use Web Services to expose information, which you can then consume via a C# (or most other languages that support wsdl), this requires configuration changes and possibly the creation of a pages or codeunits to show the information.

There are some samples at Freddy's blog [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freddyk/2010/01/20/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from-c-using-service-reference-code-version/)

Web services can be back-ported to at least 5.0 and possibly further back.

Another approach is use the C/ODBC driver to connect to NAV which you should be able to implement with some kind of wrapper in C#, the documentation is included on the installation media with each version.

A third approach would be to write a query directly to the database, you could also use views and stored procedures here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, its not possible. However you can do it in SQL if its not a proprietary database